# Error al agregar, actualizar y eliminar registros en aplicación Windows Forms con .mdf

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, asp.net, windows-forms, entity-framework

actualmente cree una aplicación sencilla en Windows Forms para la creación de usuarios y ventas, el proyecto esta realizado con c# .net, Entity Framework y estoy usando una base de datos en mdf.

Al ejecutar mi proyecto desde Visual Studio todo funciona bien, el error lo tengo al crear el ejecutable, pues el sistema puede consultar la información sin problema, pero no puede hacer ninguna actualización(crear, actualizar, eliminar) en la base de datos, siempre retorna `An error occurred while updating the entries. see the inner exception for details`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como estoy guardando el registro.

```
public bool Save(Usuarios usuario)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new VentasDBEntities())
            {
                db.Usuarios.Add(usuario);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _mensaje = ex.Message + " \n " + ex.InnerException.ToString();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Y este es un mensaje detallado del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado buscando sobre ese readonly pero no se en donde lo configuro en la base de datos mdf.

Esta es mi cadena de conexión:

`<add name="VentasDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.ModelDB.csdl|res://*/Model.ModelDB.ssdl|res://*/Model.ModelDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\VentasDB.mdf;Integrated Security = False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Comment: Imposible contestar una pregunta sobre errores en código sin ver sl código. Te sugiero que copies y pegues tu código como texto editando tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Hola amigo acabo de actualizar la pregunta muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrían ser varios los motivos por los que te da el error de los permisos.

Revisa como tienes puesta la cadena de conexión y fíjate que no haya ninguna propiedad que sea `ReadOnly` (No lo podemos apreciar, ya que no has puesto el código).

Puede que la aplicación no tenga permisos suficientes para poder modificar archivos en según que carpetas, por lo que deberías mirar de dar permisos totales a la carpeta donde se aloja el `MDF` o ejecutar la aplicación con permisos de administrador para comprobar que no sea ese el fallo.

Comment: Hola Marc muchas gracias por tu respuesta, acabo de agregar la cadena de conexión que se genero para esta DB, pero no veo nada relacionado con el read-only, incluso abrí esta base de datos en sql server y la propiedad read-only está en false

Comment: @AndrésGutiérrez Revisa la segunda parte de la respuesta, mira el tema permisos, segun veo en la captura de pantalla lo tienes puesto todo en C:\ProgramFiles(x86) y esa carpeta normalmente va con permisos limitados. Mira de dar permisos totales a la carpeta donde tienes alojada la BD o de ejecutar como administrador la aplicación como te comento en la respuesta

Comment: en lo correcto este era el problema, a la hora de generar el ejecutable, en donde se instala queda con estos permisos de solo lectura, sabes como puedo modificar esto para que no me pase?

Comment: @AndrésGutiérrez Siempre puedes indicar un path donde quieres que se guarde y donde el usuario que lo ejecuta siempre tenga permisos, como por ejemplo la carpeta de usuario